# flutter kotlin version mismatch

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build an apk for my app. I am using the share plus plug in and every time I try to build the apk I am given an error.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my error message:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3356 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
e: C:/Users/chase/lineoftheday/build/share_plus/.transforms/bf386bef8571f8dfa116064a040a5f5f/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/share_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1ef430611002ea02c2a417d6a8e7a0fc/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.10/72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.10/72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.10/72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/chase/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.10/dafaf2c27f27c09220cee312df10917d9a5d97ce/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I read and followed every similar thread that I could find, and nothing has helped. I have tried every version of kotlin and gradle. I have recreated the flutter app, deleted the cache, everything that I have read that could help, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i delete this dependencies
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.10"
in build.gradle file